# Java target annotation for interface

Tags: java, annotations

Do you know what this code does:

```
@Target(ElementType.Method)
public @interface Example{ }
```

I don't understand annotations in Java.

Comment: Did you read the [`@Target`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Target.html) documentation?

Comment: Your last statement indicates that you should do some research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you implement an annotation, you need to tell two things to the compiler:

- where it can be applied (that's your `@Target` here);
- what its retention policy is (aptly named `@RetentionPolicy`; some annotations are kept only at the source level, others at runtime).

Your target here means this annotation only applies to methods, therefore you'll have:

```
@Example
void myMethod() {}
```

But this:

```
@Example
int x;
```

is not legal (bad target).

Optionally you can tell that this annotation should be `@Documented` in the javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

"@Target(ElementType.Method)" means, that you can apply this only to methods.

Check this for more details http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html